# useEffect to scroll to bottom not working

Tags: reactjs, scroll

So this is my code, testing out a chatbot. useEffect is not working when I refresh, the automatic scroll doesn't work when new message is being received or sent.. what am I missing?

```
import './App.css';
import './normal.css';
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {

  const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [chatLog, setChatLog] = useState([{
    user: "gpt",
    message: "Hello World"
  }])

  function clearChat(){
    setChatLog([]);
  }

useEffect(() => {
    messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
  }, [chatLog]);

  async function handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let chatLogNew = [...chatLog, { user: "me", message: `${input}` } ]
    await setInput("");
    setChatLog(chatLogNew)

    const messages = chatLogNew.map((message) => message.message).join("\n")

    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3080/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: messages
      })
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    setChatLog([...chatLogNew, { user: "gpt", message: `${data.message}`}])

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <aside className ="sidemenu">
        <div className="title">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="side-menu-button" onClick={clearChat}>
          <span>+</span>
          New chat
        </div>
      </aside>
      <section className="chatbox">
        <div className="chat-log">
          {chatLog.map((message, index) => (
            <ChatMessage key={index} message={message} />
          ))}
        </div>
        <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
        <div className="chat-input-holder">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input 
              rows="1"
              value={input}
              onChange={(e)=> setInput(e.target.value)}
              className="chat-input-textarea">
              </input>
            </form>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

const ChatMessage = ({ message }) => {
  return (
    <div className={`chat-message ${message.user === "gpt" && "chatgpt"}`}>
            <div className="chat-message-center">
            <div className={`avatar ${message.user === "gpt" && "chatgpt"}`}>

              {message.user === "gpt" && "AI"}

              {message.user === "me" && "Me"}
              
              </div>
              <div className="message">
                {message.message}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Defined the messagesEndRef and inserted the useEffect and put in the dummy div to the last rendered message.

Any ideas? Am I formatting it wrong?

> EDIT:
>
> It's working now but I have to have chat-log set to "overflow:scroll"
> otherwise it doesn't kick in.. for example "overflow:auto" doesn't
> work.
>
> When it DOES work, it also doesn't scroll to the very end of the box
> but slightly above.
>
> Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding this code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const chatLogElement = messagesEndRef.current;
    const currentScrollTop = chatLogElement.scrollTop;
    const targetScrollTop = chatLogElement.scrollHeight - chatLogElement.clientHeight;
    const scrollDiff = targetScrollTop - currentScrollTop;
    let startTime;
  
    function scroll(timestamp) {
      if (!startTime) {
        startTime = timestamp;
      }
  
      const elapsedTime = timestamp - startTime;
      const progress = elapsedTime / 200;
  
      chatLogElement.scrollTop = currentScrollTop + (scrollDiff * progress);
  
      if (progress < 1) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
      }
    }
  
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
  }, [chatLog.length]);
```

Now it works, even when overflow is set to "auto"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using chatLog in the second argument array of useEffect(), use [JSON.stringify(chatLog)] or chatLog.length

```
useEffect(() => {
    messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
  }, [JSON.stringify(chatLog)]);
```

Comment: None of the suggested works sadly.. I still have to manually scroll when overflow is triggered in the chatLog.

Comment: Ok, I think you stuck in render time add setTimeout on 500 on scroll event
`if(messagesEndRef.current){
 setTimeout(() => {
  messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
 }, 500);
}
`

Comment: Also not working, not even in combination with timeout and the suggested stringifying :(  It's just not kicking in..

Answer (score 0):

scrollIntoViewOptions are:

**behavior** (Optional)

Defines the transition animation. One of auto or smooth. Defaults to auto.

**block** (Optional)

Defines vertical alignment. One of start, center, end, or nearest. Defaults to start.

**inline** (Optional)

Defines horizontal alignment. One of start, center, end, or nearest. Defaults to nearest.

So, you will need to add block option to end.

```
useEffect(() => {
    messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end" })
  }, [chatLog]);
```

Comment: Also not working..

Comment: remove <div ref={messagesEndRef} /> and change the code from <div className="chat-log"> to 
<div className="chat-log" ref={messagesEndRef}>
I mean you will need to use ref and scrollIntoView to the div that has scrollbar.

Comment: Did it like that, still no luck, damn.

Comment: try timeout function

setTimeout(function () {
           messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({
               behavior: "smooth",
               block: "end",
           });
      }, 100);

Comment: hey it's working now, but it doesn't scroll all the way down. I can see the chat messages going up but it's not scrolling to the last one, only slightly.